# Make absolute positioned parent appear on top of absolute positioned child

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to make an absolute positioned child appear behind its absolute positioned parent. The blue parent should appear above red child.

I tried setting `z-index: -1` on the child, but that makes red child not visible.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  background-color:grey;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.parent {
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.child {
  position:absolute;
  top:-5px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dwil30/mh3qw64x/

Comment: Is it 100% necessary that you keep this parent/child relationship on the divs? It is much simpler if they are siblings

Comment: ideally yes. because i'm using jquery draggable on the parent so i'd like to keep the parent/child relationship in tact. But if moving to siblings is only way, I'll have to do that...

Comment: Could you not get a kinda best of both? Make a grandparent element that is draggable which is the same size as parent. parent and child then become siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... it seems a bit hacky, but its your call :)

You need to specify `z-index` of the `container` since otherwise the renderer has no "base" value to compare your child with.

Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cmvwLseo/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Separate the child and parent divs so they're both positioned relative to a common "container" then update your logic to position the child accordingly and set the z-index property of each.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  background-color:grey;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.parent {
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index:2;
}
.child {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left: 90px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color:red;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```